# Video conferencing with Kinect

Tags: kinect, video-processing, kinect-sdk

I am doing a project about video conferencing using Kinect.

However, I am not familiar with C#. Therefore, I would like to ask if there are books or/and websites available explaining how to program with it.

Remarks: I do it by Kinect SDK

Thanks

Comment: Thank you all. :) I think I am looking for something about video transmission with C#. Do you have any ideas of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three books might help you out :

- [Start Here!™ Learn Microsoft® Visual C#® 2010](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145319210.do)
- [Start Here!™ Fundamentals of Microsoft® .NET Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145330536.do)
- [Start Here!™ Learn the Kinect™ API (Good book if you're new to Kinect SDK](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145338785.do)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) site has excellent examples of code. It's a good way to start.